# Use d3-transition as a separate npm module

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to

```
import { transition } from 'd3-transition'
```

and add an update transition to this code, but I can't figure it out how to use the transition library separately.

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";

 //...

 const binding = select(host.svg)
    .select("#points")
    .selectAll("circle.point")
    .data(data);

  const enter = binding.enter();

  enter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", (d) => projection(d)[0])
    .attr("cy", (d) => projection(d)[1])
    .attr("r", (d) => radius(d.count));
```

I realize I can just import the whole d3 library, but I'm doing it this way intentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here:

- how to import transition with ES6?
- how to add an update transition?

To import d3-transition, your import is correct:

```js
import { transition } from 'd3-transition'
```

To add an update transition, you can use [selection.join()](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join). selection.join() takes a function per selection: one for the enter, update and exit selection.

To track update changes, note that you need to provide a [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) to D3, otherwise it won't be able to tell what changed. A key function will identify uniquely each of your data.

Finally, use selection.call() to avoid breaking the method chain.

You can see the full example at the link.

```js
  svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    // Key function to track updates
    .data(data, d => d)
    // https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join
    .join(
      // Enter selection handler
      enter =>
        enter
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", 100)
          .attr("height", d => d.value)
          .attr("x", (d, i) => 150 * i) // spacing
          .attr("fill", "red"),
      // Update selection handler
      update =>
        update.attr("fill", "green").call(update =>
          update
            .transition()
            .duration(3000)
            .attr("height", d => d.value)
        )
    );
```

[Example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-herschel-xvolk?file=/src/index.js). Make sure to refresh the browser to see the transition.